# Multiple features as input for ML NLP Text analysis prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having 8 columns as input and 1 output column to predict. While trying to fit countvectorizer and tfidf I am getting

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7, 23752]
```

But `X_train.shape` and `X.shape` is correct then when I am applying fit_transform why I am getting this error?

Code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['A','B','C',
                                                   'D','E','F',
                                                   'G']], df.final, test_size=0.2, 
random_state = 42)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

nb = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
           ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
           ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
          ])
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[Notebook_Code_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fKCC.png)

Comment: can you print the shapes?

Comment: print(df.shape) =====> (29691, 8)
print(X_train.shape)===> (23752, 7)
print(y_train.shape)  ===> ((23752,))

Answer (score 0):

CountVectorizer is applied on a string, not NumPy arrays.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

TfidfTransformer will work on CountVectorizer count matrix,s o your pipeline doesn't make sense, you are also missing parameters.

As you have the numpy array representation already, just fit the NB classifier directly.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['A','B','C',
                                                   'D','E','F',
                                                   'G']], df.final, test_size=0.2, 
random_state = 42)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: I did above mentioneed way but now i am getting :- 
ValueError: could not convert string to float:       Seems I need to use .fit to convert all string to numbers.Please suggest.

Comment: can you print X_train[0] and y_train[0]?

Comment: print(X_train[0]) is throwing Key error. And X_train.head(1) is printing 1st row data , all in text.

Comment: Kindly, add a sample of X_train.head() and y_train.head() so that I understand your structure.